# Iteration over the state object

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, asyncstorage

I am storing some data in the AsyncStorage and then getting it in componentdidmount and setting the state. till here I m doing fine but I am unable to iterate over the data to show it in the flatlist component.

***State and componentDidMount code***

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
  state ={ cart:"" }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cart')
    this.setState({cart:JSON.parse(item)})
  }
```

With `this.state.cart` I get this object

```
Object {
  "cart": Array [
    Object {
      "count": 1,
      "key": "NK01",
      "name": "Mohanjo Beaded Choker",
      "pic": "img1",
      "price": "1200",
    },
    Object {
      "count": 1,
      "key": "ID01",
      "name": "Silver Glass",
      "pic": "img3",
      "price": "9400",
    },
    Object {
      "count": 1,
      "key": "ID03",
      "name": "Ganesh With Kalash",
      "pic": "img2",
      "price": "3570",
    },
  ],
  "total": 3,
}
```

I want to iterate over `this.state.cart.cart` but when I used map function it throws an error that this is not a function. Checked its type shows the object and with Array.isArray shows true but this unable to get the length and iterate.

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.cart` is a an array so you can use map function to display the elements of the array:

```js
class Cart extends React.Component {
  state ={ cart:[] }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cart')
    this.setState(JSON.parse(item))
  }

this.state.cart?.map(cart =>
        <div key={cart.key}>
          <h4>{cart.name}</h4>
          <p>{cart.price}</p>
        </div>
      );
```

Comment: this.state.cart.map shows error that it is not a function